# setContentView() not changing layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried to change the layout of MainActivity from `activity_main(xml)` to `firebase(xml)` using `setContentView()`.

The problem is that activity_main layout is still showing when the activity is on even though i have changed it to `firebase layout`. Here are my codes

Before changing to firebase(xml)

```
public class MainActivity extends SimpleActivity {
  private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
  private EditText email, password;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

After changing to firebase(xml)

```
public class MainActivity extends SimpleActivity {
  private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
  private EditText email, password;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.firebase);
}
```

XML for activity_main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:gravity="center">
```

XML for firebase xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/firebase"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.johnson.myapplication.MainActivity">
```

Please note that these two attributes

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.johnson.myapplication.MainActivity">
```

were formally for activity_main layout. I removed it and added it to firebase layout attributes

Comment: share your firebase xml.

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: @HemantParmar i've done that now

Comment: @OğuzhanDöngül yes I did, still the same

Comment: you passed wrong context, just remove this tools:context="com.example.johnson.myapplication.MainActivity" line to your firebase xml :

Comment: how you know layout not changing, ?both layout have no child view.

Comment: @HemantParmar they do, i copied only the root view. I think activity_main xml has been attached somewhere with MainActivity in such a way that even though i changed it, it's still showing

Comment: no its not, i am telling you just add single textview in firebase xml check textview showing or not.

Comment: Post code of SimpleActivity also